# How to send data from an event listener to paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I need to create a button which does some computation and gives me a list and I need to use that list in my paint and make lines of those coordinates. Whats the best way for me to send the data from the event listener to my paint method? Thank you!

Comment: can you please supply much more info? what have you tried so far? 

The better the question, the better the answers get.

Answer (score 0):

You dont give us enough info and you ask a lot of things, so here is a rough outline to get you started with awt/swing buttons, and you can lookup the rest from there or ask more specific questions like how to setup custom painting etc. See comments in the code below with explanations.

Create a publicly available array or list to store your co-ordinates. This is what we will use to share info between the event listener and your paint method:

```
public static LinkedList<Point> myCoOrdinateList = new LinkedList<>();
```

Add an action listener to your button something like this:

```
myButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {
        //do something to get your new co-ords / point
        //      
        //your code here to get X and Y

        //assign X and Y to a point:
        Point myNewPoint = new Point(X, Y);

        //add that point to the list
        myCoOrdinateList.add(myNewPoint);

        //repaint your graph or your custom paint component here (or whatever else you are drawing these lines to):
        myComponent.repaint();
    }
});
```

And if you are doing the painting by overriding the paint method of a component then you could add something like this in your paint method:

```
//create graphics so we can draw lines
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
//we need to work with 2 points so we will store one point here:
Point previous = new Point(0, 0);
for (Iterator<Point> iterator = myCoOrdinateList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
{
    //get point
    Point nextPoint = iterator.next();
    //link previous point and next pint in the co-ordinates list:
    g2d.drawLine(previous.x, previous.y, nextPoint.x, nextPoint.y);
    //set new previous point so the next line is ready to be drawn
    previous = nextPoint;
}
```

Here is some more info from the official java tutorials. I suggest you read through these links before asking any more questions.

Custom painting:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html

Working with graphics / drawing things:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html

More info on working with swing buttons:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html